# how to edit or modify or change a single line in a large text file with R

Tags: r

i'm reading some large text files into databases with R but they contain illegal field names for the database software.  the column names of the large text files are just in the first row -- is it possible to edit only that first row without cycling through every single row in the file (which seems like a waste of resources)?

here are two examples of what i'm trying to do with some example data.  the first reads everything into ram - so that won't work for my large data tables.  the second would work, but it's slow because it processes every line in the file.

i suppose it's important that the solution work across platforms *and* not require the installation of external software (aside from R packages), just because i'll be sharing this script with others and would rather not ask them to perform more steps than necessary.  i'm looking for the fastest way to do this *within R only*  :)

```
# create two temporary files
tf <- tempfile() ; tf2 <- tempfile()

# write the mtcars data table to a file on the disk
write.csv( mtcars , tf )

# look at the first three lines
readLines( tf , n = 3 )

# read in the entire table
z <- readLines( tf )

# make the only substitution i care about
z[1] <- gsub( 'disp' , 'newvar' , z[1] )

# write the entire table back out to the table
writeLines( z , tf2 )

# confirm the replacement
readLines( tf2 , 2 )
# done!

# # # # # # # OR

# blank out the output file
file.remove( tf2 )

# create a file connection to the text file
incon <- file( tf , "r" )

# create a second file connection to the secondary temporary file
outcon <- file( tf2 , "w" )

# read in one line at a time
while( length( one.line <- readLines( incon , 1 ) ) > 0 ){

    # make the substitution on every line
    one.line <- gsub( 'disp' , 'newvar' , one.line )

    # write each line to the second temporary file
    writeLines( one.line , outcon )
}

# close the connections
close( incon ) ; close( outcon )

# confirm the replacement
readLines( tf2 , 2 )
# done!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you edit just the header, and then read the rest in chunks? I don't know how big this file is, but perhaps in blocks of lines (I've guessed 10000). Depending on how much memory you have you can adjust this to be bigger or smaller.

```
##setup
tf <- tempfile(); tf2 <- tempfile()
write.csv(mtcars,tf)

fr <- file(tf, open="rt") #open file connection to read
fw <- file(tf2, open="wt") #open file connection to write 
header <- readLines(f,n=1) #read in header
header <- gsub( 'disp' , 'newvar' , header) #modify header    
writeLines(header,con=fw) #write header to file
while(length(body <- readLines(fr,n=10000)) > 0) {
  writeLines(body,fw) #pass rest of file in chunks of 10000
}
close(fr);close(fw) #close connections
#unlink(tf);unlink(tf2) #delete temporary files
```

It should be faster because R will run through the `while` loop every 10000 lines instead of every single line. Additionally, R will call `gsub` on just the line you want, instead of every line, saving you R time. R can't edit a file "in-place", so to speak, so there is no way around reading and copying the file. If you have to do it in R, then make your chunks as big as memory allows and then pass your file through.

I saw a 3x performance difference between the two ways:

```
#test file creation ~3M lines
tf <- tempfile(); tf2 <- tempfile()
fw <- file(tf,open="wt")
sapply(1:1e6,function(x) write.csv(mtcars,fw))
close(fw)

#my way
system.time({
fr <- file(tf, open="rt") #open file connection to read
fw <- file(tf2, open="wt") #open file connection to write 
header <- readLines(f,n=1) #read in header
header <- gsub( 'disp' , 'newvar' , header) #modify header    
writeLines(header,con=fw) #write header to file
while(length(body <- readLines(fr,n=10000)) > 0) {
  writeLines(body,fw) #pass rest of file in chunks of 10000
}
close(fr);close(fw) #close connections
})    
#   user  system elapsed 
#  32.96    1.69   34.85 

#OP's way
system.time({
incon <- file( tf , "r" )
outcon <- file( tf2 , "w" )
while( length( one.line <- readLines( incon , 1 ) ) > 0 ){
    one.line <- gsub( 'disp' , 'newvar' , one.line )
    writeLines( one.line , outcon )
}
close( incon ) ; close( outcon )
})
#   user  system elapsed 
# 104.36    1.92  107.03
```

Comment: sorry, i am really confused how this is different from my second example (aside from a larger `n=` in the `readLines`)?  the files have 15 million records in them, so reading the whole thing in is slow and i was hoping for a quicker edit :(

Answer (score 8):

You're using the wrong tool for this. Use some command line tool instead. E.g. using `sed`, smth like `sed -i '1 s/disp/newvar/' file` should do. And if you *have to* do this in R, use

```
filename = 'myfile'
scan(pipe(paste("sed -i '1 s/disp/newvar/' ", filename, sep = "")))
```

Here's a windows-specific version:

```
filename = 'myfile'
tf1 = tempfile()
tf2 = tempfile()

# read header, modify and write to file
header = readLines(filename, n = 1)
header = gsub('disp', 'newvar', header)
writeLines(header, tf1)

# cut the rest of the file to a separate file
scan(pipe(paste("more ", filename, " +1 > ", tf2)))

# append the two bits together
file.append(tf1, tf2)

# tf1 now has what you want
```

Comment: yes, i have to use R for this..  the command `scan( pipe( paste0( "sed -i '1 s/disp/newvar/' " , "'" , tf , "'" )  ) )` did not work.. i've never used `pipe` or `scan` or `sed` before -- what's the appropriate syntax and why?  thanks :D

Comment: @AnthonyDamico -- Those are (nifty) *NIX command-line tools that *NIX users often assume everyone has access easy access to. Also, IIRC, Windows users don't even have access to the `pipe()` command, which relies on an underlying *NIX-based pipe utility.

Comment: I made the `scan` code more explicit. Just google those and you'll find much better explanation of what each does than I can or am willing to:) do. Also, as Josh pointed out this is Linux/Unix only.

Comment: well, `scan` and `pipe` work on windows as well, so you can use them together with your favorite command line tool (there IS a windows version of `sed`)

Comment: yes, but asking users of my script to install an additional program is still probably slower than the second option i've proposed in my original question - at least in human-time  :(

Comment: I added a windows-specific version for you

Comment: @eddi nope, that `more` command does not work for me at all.  first, i think the `>` is backward.. but then looking at the `more help` screen, it's not clear that you can use it to read one file into another (skipping the first line)..  :(  are you sure that syntax is correct?

Comment: @eddi also, does that mean this will not work on macintosh or *nix?  i've revised my question to ask for something cross-platform and not requiring an install-- otherwise my example is just more convenient :(

Comment: Code works for me as is on Windows 2008 and Windows 7 - what error are you getting running `more file +1 > file_out` in command line? The windows-specific version will, by definition, work on windows only. I'm guessing the linux version will work on macs. If you go in this direction, you can use `Sys.info` to branch by OS.

Comment: @eddi the files have to be inside quotes if there's a space in the filename..  it's still hanging on my computer and it's really not cross-platform, so i'm giving up and going with the other answer -- but your initial recommendation is much better for non-windows :)  thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
iocon <- file("originalFile","r+")
header <- readLines(iocon,n=1)
header <- gsub('disp', 'newvar', header)
writeLines(header, con=iocon)
```

This would just overwrite the first line and depending on how it manages system resources could be very efficient. Be sure to have backup.

Comment: this does not work.  for example  `tf <- tempfile() ;
writeLines( "hi\nhello" , tf ) ;
iocon <- file(tf,"r+") ;
header <- readLines(iocon,n=1) ;
header <- gsub('hi', 'howdy', header) ;
writeLines(header, con=iocon) ;
close(iocon) ;
readLines( tf )`