# Modify a .bib file from R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

In the example below, I generate the bibliography for packages from a chunk of code. However, there is an error in the BibTeX entry for one package. I could modify this entry manually but my change will be overwritten next time I knit my file.

Therefore, I would like to know if it is possible to modify the line in the .bib file from a chunk in R Markdown, so that the entry is automatically corrected each time the file is knitted.

Example:

````
---
title: "Cite R packages"
author: ''
date: ""
output:
  pdf_document
bibliography: mistakeref.bib
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
# If not installed yet: 
# install.packages("cem")
```

This is a citation of a paper: @R-cem 

```{r cite-packages, echo=FALSE}
knitr::write_bib("cem", file = "mistakeref.bib", tweak = TRUE)
```
````

`mistakeref.bib` will be created by the code, but there is an error in the Bibtex entry for the package `cem`. I would like to replace:

`author = {{Iacus} and Stefano M. and {King} and {Gary} and {Porro} and {Giuseppe}},`

by:

`author = {Stefano M. Iacus and Gary King and Giuseppe Porro},`

Basically, it would be a sort of automatic "search and replace" from R. I have some trouble understanding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886048/how-to-edit-or-modify-or-change-a-single-line-in-a-large-text-file-with-r) and I am not sure if it corresponds to what I would like to do.

Comment: Why not editing the .bib file in the first place? Anyway try `readLines` and `gsub`.

Comment: I don't understand your question, and I have an error with `invalid regular expression` due to curly brackets in `gsub`. Could you show me how to do so? I didn't put it in my post but I have several packages in the .bib file and only one with a mistake

Comment: Actually you could just replace the whole line using `grep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in the .bib file using `readLines`. Then use `grep` to identify the "bad" line (`.` is a special character, so we need to escape using `\\.`). Then just replace and save using `cat`.

```
l <- readLines("mybib.bib")
l[grep("Stefano M\\.", l)] <- 
  "  author = {Stefano M. Iacus and Gary King and Giuseppe Porro},"
cat(l, sep="\n", file="mybib1.bib")
```

Just extend the `grep` regex until there is one single match.

Comment: Ideally you’d want to match the *exact* line you want to replace to avoid false positives. There’s really no reason to use an approximate match here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You may easily put the exact match into the `grep`.

Comment: And yet your answer doesn’t do that …

Comment: @KonradRudolph So the comments add something useful to the post, don't they?